# Why don't Nobuchika Ginoza and Tomomi Masaoka share the same last name?

Tags: psycho-pass

It's revealed in the last episode that:

> Nobuchika GINOZA is Tomomi MASAOKA's son.

But, I don't understand why they don't share the same last name. There must be a particular reason for this.

Comment: A cursory search of the Japanese internet suggests that no currently-existing material explains why this is the case. It certainly isn't explained in the anime, so any explanation would have to come out of one of the side materials (e.g. the _Kanshikan Tsunemori Akane_ manga, the _Psycho-Pass 0_ novelization, etc.).

Comment: Thanks anyway, and I thought it was one of Japanese culture that I'm unaware of :) Or who knows maybe in the world of Psycho-Pass it's a normal thing.

Comment: Perhaps the latter took their mother's maiden name, because the former was estranged or separated?

Comment: @Krazer By "the latter", you mean Tomomi, and "the former" you mean Nobuchika? I think it should be the opposite, since Tomomi was a latent criminal, and his son Nobuchika was bullied at school. That may lead to Nobuchika's mother decision to changed his last name to her maiden name, which is Ginoza. Nice theory :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because his father was demoted and became an enforcer, Nobuchika was ashamed, so he picked his mother's last name instead. His mother is Akiho Ginoza.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably it's because otherwise his name would raise too much suspicion and intervene with his life. Many people in real life carry their mother's maiden name for similar reasons, so it's not surprising.